# Counting faces on multipermutahedra/multipermutohedra

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, permutations

A *multipermutahedron* is the convex hull of all permutations of a list of numbers. For example, $\Pi(0,1,2)$ generates a regular hexagon, and $\Pi(0,1,1,2)$ generates a cuboctahedron.

In general, given a permutahedron such as $\Pi(0,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4),$ faces are determined by partitions of the ordered list with the property that parts of the partitions of length greater than $1$ contain at least two distinct elements.  (See the paper *The Combinatorics of Permutation Polytopes* by Billera and Sarangarajan.)  So $0112|2234|4|4$ determines a face, which is the product of a cuboctahedron and a truncated tetrahedron.  Note that $0112|2234|44$ generates the same face, since the $44$ part degenerates to a point, so we essentially make sure there is a one-to-one correspondence between suitable partitions and faces.

I have results for many specific cases, but I have not been able to find any general results (e.g., *not* just looking at simple polytopes), either for the $f$-vectors or for counting this type of partition.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to write down a generating function, though I don't know
how useful it will be to you. The number of ordered partitions of the
multiset $\{ 0^{m_0}, 1^{m_1},\dots\}$ into $k$ blocks such that each
block of more than one element contains at least two distinct elements
is the coefficient of $x_0^{m_0}x_1^{m_1}\cdots$ in
 $$ \left( \frac{1}{(1-x_0)(1-x_1)\cdots}-1-\sum_{i\geq
 0}\frac{x_i^2}{1-x_i}\right)^k. $$

Comment: Let me clarify with an example.  Consider the $n$-dimensional simplex $0^n1.$  The number of ordered partitions into $k$ blocks should always be $1$ since there is only one type of face of a given dimension on a simplex.  When I calculate the count directly using the formula above, I find that the coefficient of $x_0^nx_1$ in $((x_0+x_0^2+x_0^3+\cdots)(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+\cdots)+x_0+x_1)^k$ is $k$ for $k\le n+1$ rather than $1.$  When $n=4$ and $k=2,$ for example, I should only get $0|0001.$  I am not sure we are both counting the same thing.

Comment: @VinceMatsko: you are right. I am counting all faces, while you are counting the different combinatorial types.